# C#: How to unmerge gridview cell when export to excel

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, export-to-excel

I have a gridview where one of the columns store date and time together.
I would like to split that column into two, one store the date and another store the time.
Is there any way to accomplish this?
Thanks.

This is the code I used to export the gridview to excel.

```
protected void exportBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    loadGridViewContent();
    Response.Clear();
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=report.xls");
    Response.Charset = "";

    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.xls";
    Response.Write(@"<style> TD {mso-number-format:\@;}</style>");
    System.IO.StringWriter stringWrite = new System.IO.StringWriter();
    System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htmlWrite = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWrite);

    HtmlForm frm = new HtmlForm();
    gvResult.Parent.Controls.Add(frm);
    frm.Controls.Add(gvResult);
    frm.RenderControl(htmlWrite);

    Response.Write(stringWrite.ToString());
    Response.End();
}
```

This is what i currently have.

> ```
>    |----------------------|
>    | 13-MAR-2013 14:24:05 |
>    |----------------------|
> ```

This is what i want to accomplish.

> ```
>    |-------------|----------|
>    | 13-MAR-2013 | 14:24:05 |
>    |-------------|----------|
> ```

Comment: will [*This*](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformsdatacontrols/thread/10d8b618-021b-41d7-8fa5-bfe22e9b94f8) help?, just add some codes, on how you will get the value of the column :)

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: Where do you want to show this column in excel or gridview?

Comment: I want to show it in excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try by adding another two columns to hold Date and Time values, hide them by set visible property as false on those columns.

before you renter set those two columns visible and hide DateTime column and render it.

to hide column

```
gvResult.Columns[columnsIndex1].visible = false;
```

to show column

```
gvResult.Columns[columnsIndex2].visible = true;

gvResult.DataBind();
```

finally render it.

```
gvResult.RenderControl(htmlWrite);
```

Comment: Ya, this is also the only way I can think of. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> This is how you can do it:

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gv" AutoGenerateColumns="false" >
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="YourDateTimeColumn" HeaderText="Date" DataFormatString="{0:MM/dd/yyyy}"/>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="YourDateTimeColumn" HeaderText="Time" DataFormatString="{0:hh:mm:tt}" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: so when you add that on your gridview, it will be exported with seperate Date Time column

Comment: But for my case, the date and time shall be displayed in the same cell to the user. During export only I need to split it into two.

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to do some rework. For export to excel you need to take a dummy gridview to which you are assigning separate columns for date and time. You will find useful code [Here](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Export-GridView-To-Word-Excel-PDF-CSV-Formats-in-ASP.Net.aspx)